# jQuery : click event on child element on the list

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script in jQuery/PHP, which receives other levels on the UL list. For example:

```
<ul class="obj">
<li>Object A</li>
<li>Object B</li>
</ul>
```

After click on the LI element, jQuery appends another list to this element received by POST:

```
<ul class="obj">
<li>Object A
<ul class="obj">
<li>Object A1</li>
<li>Object A2</li>
</ul>
</li>
</li>Object B</li>
```

Then when I want to click on 'Object A1' element and append another list to it, list appends to parent element, because both are ".obj li" elements..
My jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
        $(".obj li").click(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            $.post('get_rel.php',
                function(data){
                    $(el).append(data)
                    el = null;
            });

        })
    })
```

How to invoke a click event exactly on the clicked (child) element?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's causing this is the `click()` handler is *only* being bound to the elements on the page at the time you call `click()`. When you add child elements to the list, the click event is bubbling up to the top level `li`, and the event handler is been triggered. Here, `this` is the top level `li`, which is why the new elements are appearing.

Instead, you should use event delegation, which will fire for all current **and future** elements, and `this` inside the handler will be the current element (the important part in this case).

```
$(document).on('click', '.obj li', function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $.post('get_rel.php',
        function(data){
            $(el).append(data)
            el = null;
    });
});
```

`on()` was introduced in 1.7, so if you're using an older version (and can't upgrade), you should use `delegate()`:

```
$(document).delegate('.obj li', 'click', function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $.post('get_rel.php',
        function(data){
            $(el).append(data)
            el = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `e.stopPropagation()` in your event handler

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help. Matt's answer resolved the problem.